# How to get the two smallest values from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to take the two smallest values from an array `x`. But when I use `np.where`:

```
A,B = np.where(x == x.min())[0:1]
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

How can I fix this error? And do I need to arange numbers in ascending order in array?

Comment: Well, the `[0:1]` slicing syntax is equal to `[:1]` syntax, which means take the first element from that array. Why don't you do something like `A, B = [np.where(x==x.min())] * 2` (unpacking a list)? You really don't need the slicing syntax, as there's only *one* minimal value in a given sequence.

Comment: do you want the **indices** of the minimal value or the lowest two values in your array? Could you include a minimal sample and demonstrate what the result should look like?

Comment: @MSeifert I want two smallest values in array.

Comment: ok, thank you for the clarification :) Could you [edit] your question accordingly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand it. I just reread the question and it still says "take two smallest values from the np.where condition". But I thought you wanted the two smallest values in `x` not from the `np.where`-condition.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what's in x and what you would like the corresponding output for A and B to be?

Comment: @MSeifert I want two smallest values in x.

Comment: @qasim Great, thank you. In that case you shouldn't use `np.where` at all. I updated your question (again), I hope I made it a bit clearer but you might want to check if it's still correct.

Comment: @MSeifert thanks. My x values are here: `[ 0.0619444   0.01415524  0.0644649   0.00348524  0.01608257  0.03753657
  0.0392854   0.0503084   0.10295524]`

Comment: And the expected output would be `0.00348524` and `0.01415524` for `A` and `B` respectivly?

Comment: @MSeifert Exactly!

Comment: @MSeifert Last question: How can I get the number of array for `0.00348524` and `0.01415524` for `A` and `B` respectively? For instance it will be `3` for `0.00348524`.

Comment: [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) instead of `np.partition` :)

Comment: @MSeifert You are wonderful. Bless you :)

Comment: @MSeifert The code sorts wrongly the numbers if the first three decimals of two numbers are the same. For instance:  `x= np.array([0.056669, 0.019477, 0.06245, 0., 0.019524, 0.058592, 0.05847, 0.078317, 0.09599])` and then `print (np.partition(x, 1)[0:9])`. The result is: `[ 0.        0.019477  0.06245   0.056669  0.019524  0.058592  0.05847
  0.078317  0.09599 ]`. This sorting is wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: `partition` only "partitions" up to `k` (the second parameter). So you only partitioned the first two items and they are correct `[0, 0.019477]`.

Comment: @MSeifert I need to sort all items :(

Comment: [`x.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy-ndarray-sort) sorts the array in-place :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) to get the lowest `k+1` items:

```
A, B = np.partition(x, 1)[0:2]  # k=1, so the first two are the smallest items
```

In Python 3.x you could also use:

```
A, B, *_ = np.partition(x, 1)
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([5, 3, 1, 2, 6])
A, B = np.partition(x, 1)[0:2]
print(A)  # 1
print(B)  # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in the code. The first is that the slice is `[0:1]` when it should be `[0:2]`. The second is actually a very common issue with `np.where`. If you look into [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you will see that it always returns a tuple, with one element if you only pass one parameter. Hence you have to access the tuple element first and then index the array normally:

```
A,B = np.where(x == x.min())[0][0:2]
```

Which will give you the two first indices containing the minimum value. If no two such indices exist you will get an exception, so you may want to check for that.

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, well, I assumed that was expected to be true, although I guess it could be checked. Btw, I understood the question as "give me the first two indices with the minimum value", although maybe it was "give me the two smallest values"?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It should give me the two smallest values. But "not_a_robot" says: there's only one minimal value in a given sequence. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `sorted` instead of `np.where`?

```
A,B = sorted(x)[:2]
```

Comment: Seems like that is how everyone is reading the question, including myself and @MSeifert. 1) Partitioning is MUCH more efficient than sorting. 2) OP is looking for multiple occurrences of the same value.